# How its the package Nito.AsyncEx in Nuget targeting multiple framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I need to know how is the package **Nito.AsyncEx** targeting multiple frameworkSslike when i install it in .Net Project or .Net Core its compatible with both of them. Is this package developed in .Net standard or is there some thing else ?

Comment: The version of the package is 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the reason is just that the package is developed in .Net standard.

You could search for the [github](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) code of the package, download and open the source code in vs. Then you will find all his class libraries  have

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: yeah thnku so much :)